# Issue reading file. IO: ("Unsupported scheme \'java+compilationUnit\'")

Tags: rascal

I have run into and issue. I have been trying to read the content of a file for an example project which contains I single file. Below you will find the code and the error which I get. I have tried running this code with Rascal version 0.22.0, 0.23.0, and 0.24,2. In all versions I have the same issue, but I do not understand what is wrong, and I am pretty sure this code worked for me over a year ago.

```
void demoFunc() {
    list[str] output = [];
    m3x = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://testProject|);
    projectFiles = files(m3x);
    for(file <- projectFiles) {
        output = readFileLines(file);
    }
}
```

```
rascal>demoFunc();
|std:///IO.rsc|(15157,756,<620,0>,<640,24>): IO("Unsupported scheme \'java+compilationUnit\'")
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///IO.rsc|(15157,756,<620,0>,<640,24>))
        at readFileLines(|project://TQM/src/Helper.rsc|(998,4,<39,26>,<39,30>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,11,<1,0>,<1,11>)ok
```

Comment: Something seems to be going wrong with the side-effect registration of the locations. What happens if you `import analysis::m3::Registry;` and call `registerProject(|project://testProject|, m3x)` yourself just after the `create` call?

Comment: That does not seem to change anything. The same issue remains, sadly.

Comment: I have tried to analyse different projects, I created a new eclipse workspace, created a new project. I tried to registering the project as you said. Nothing seems to fix it. Do you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the latest rascal-eclipse release has a new bug. To work around this one you could resolve the source file from the logical name yourself:

```
loc sourceFile(loc logical, M3 model) {
  if (loc f <- model.declarations[logical]) {
    return f;
  }
  
  throw FileNotFound(logical);
}
```

That simulates what `analysis::m3::Registry` would have done for you. The returned `loc` is a slice of the file where the declared entity is found. If you want the entire file, use `myLoc.top`.